# I'm trying to use an attribute from class 'Board' in another class 'MCNode'

Tags: python

I am trying to use variables from one class in another. I'm not sure how to get rid of this problem. I want to be able to do this, does anyone have any suggestions. The error I'm getting is: AttributeError: 'MCNode' object has no attribute 'board'

```
class StudentAI():

    def __init__(self,col,row,p):
        self.col = col
        self.row = row
        self.p = p
        self.board = Board(col,row,p)
        self.board.initialize_game()
        self.color = ''
        self.opponent = {1:2, 2:1}
        self.color = 2

class MCNode():

    parent = None
    boardstate = None
    gameboard = None
    col = 0
    row = 0
    p = 0
    children = []
    color = 2
    # whitewon = 0
    # blackwon = 0
    wins = 0
    game_color = 0
    depth = 0
    maxdepth = 15
    visits = 0
    c = math.sqrt(2)
    opponent = {1:2,2:1}

    def __init__(self, boardstate, gameboard, col, row, color, game_color, parent=None):
        if parent != None:
            self.parent = parent
            self.depth = parent.depth + 1
        self.children = []
        self.col = col
        self.row = row
        # boardstate will be static copy of board stored in every node
        self.boardstate = boardstate
        # gameboard will be the board which constantly changes
        self.gameboard = gameboard
        self.game_color = game_color
        self.color = color
        # self.whitewon = 0
        # self.blackwon = 0
        self.wins = 0
        self.visits = 0
        self.maxdepth = 15
        self.opponent = {1:2,2:1}


In a function inside the class McNode, I'm trying to do: 
"current_piece = self.board.board[c][r]"
but I'm getting the error "AttributeError: 'MCNode' object has no attribute 'board'"
Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can tweak this code to do what I'm trying to do?
```

Comment: you have `self.gameboard` and `self.boardstate` but don't have a `self.board` property, what are you expecting that to do?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I want to be able to use self.board from StudentAI class in MCNode class. How do I do that?

Comment: ok, does `MCNode` maintain an instance of the `StudentAI` class? if so in which property?